# Should I force my 4 year boy to play sports or activities?

Tags: pre-schooler, development, activities, sports

He refused to join any activity (Karate/Gymnastics/Tennis). He doesn't even want to join church lessons for kids (Sunday school).

Shall I force him or wait until he is 6?